# make a simple translator with python

Tags: python, list

I wrote this app with python:

```
mylist = []
mydict = {}
mystr = ""

num = int(input())

for i in list(range(num)):
        mylist.append(input())
for i in list(range(len(mylist))):
    temp =  mylist[i].split()
    mydict[temp[0]] = temp[1:4]
word = input()

word_s = word.split()

for i in mydict.keys():
    for x in list(range(len(word_s))):
        if word_s[x] in mydict[i]:
           mystr = mystr + f"{i} "

print(mystr)
```

but I want when I give this input To the app:

```
4
man I je ich
kheili very très sehr
alaghemand interested intéressé interessiert 
barnamenevisi programming laprogrammation Programmierung
I am very interested in programming
```

get This output:

```
man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi
```

I Tested

```
else:
    mystr = mystr + f"{word_s[x]} "
```

but it is not working and output is: man am very interested in programming I am kheili interested in programming I am very alaghemand in programming I am very interested in barnamenevisi

please help me to get This output

Comment: what output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to translate from e.g. English to Farsi, you use an *English to Farsi* dictionary, not a Farsi to (English, French, German) dictionary. Since you already know the English word you want to translate, you can look up the Farsi equivalent from the dictionary easily. On the other hand, if you use a Farsi to (English, French, German) dictionary like you do, you'd need to go through *every Farsi word in the dictionary*, see if the English equivalent matches the word you're looking for, and then use the Farsi word for it.

Since you want to translate *from* English here, the keys of your dictionary should be English words. Since you want to take the input in multiple languages, you can create a list of the words in each language, and then create a dictionary using the words of the *from* and *to* languages you need.

```
num_words = 4 # int(input("How many words? "))

languages = ["Farsi", "English", "French", "German"]
words = []

print("Please enter words in this order, separated by a single space:")
print(" ".join(languages))

for _ in range(num_words):
    words = input("> ").split()
```

At the end of this, you should have `words` looking like so:

```
[['man', 'I', 'je', 'ich'],
 ['kheili', 'very', 'très', 'sehr'],
 ['alaghemand', 'interested', 'intéressé', 'interessiert'],
 ['barnamenevisi', 'programming', 'laprogrammation', 'Programmierung']]
```

Each row is the translation for a single word.

Next, we can create our translation dictionary:

```
print("Language options: ")
for index, lang in enumerate(languages):
    print(f"{index}. {lang}")

from_lang = 1 # int(input(f"Input language [0-{len(languages)}]: "))
to_lang = 0 # int(input(f"Output language [0-{len(languages)}]: "))


translation_dict = dict()
for w in words:
    from_word = w[from_lang]
    to_word = w[to_lang]
    translation_dict[from_word] = to_word

# Or, as a comprehension:
translation_dict = {w[from_lang]: w[to_lang] for w in words}
```

`translation_dict` now looks like an English to Farsi dictionary:

```
{'I': 'man',
 'very': 'kheili',
 'interested': 'alaghemand',
 'programming': 'barnamenevisi'}
```

Now, we're ready to ask for the sentence. Then, we iterate over each word, find its translation in the dictionary, and add that to our output:

```
sentence = input("Enter something to translate\n> ")
output_words = [] # Add translated words to an output list because it's more efficient than a string

for original_word in sentence.split():
    translated_word = translation_dict.get(original_word, original_word)
    # dict.get(A, B) returns the value of the key A, defaulting to B if the key is not found
    output_words.append(translated_word)

# Or, as a comprehension
output_words = [translation_dict.get(w, w) for w in sentence.split()]


print("Translation:")
print(" ".join(output_words)) # Join the output list with spaces and print
```

Which, given the input `I am very interested in programming` outputs `man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi`

Answer (score -1):

this should do

```
word = "I am very interested in programming"
for k, v in mydict.items():
    for word_s in word.split():
        if word_s in v:
           word=word.replace(word_s, k)
print(word)
>>> man am kheili alaghemand in barnamenevisi
```